# How to store sequential data in rails avoiding RACE condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to store a unique reference number in a column (after reading numbers that already exist). I don't want to use database locks, as they will slow down the process. I also do not want to do this in `after_create` callback, as it will add a query. Is there any other way to handle the race condition?

Comment: Also i dont want to do this in after_create callback, as it will add a query.

Comment: "I store a unique reference number in a column" Sounds like the application is generating that unique number.. "Is there any other way to handle the race condition?" Just use the database `AUTO_INCREMENT` option instead to generate a unique number it's race condition free..

Comment: that sequence is year-month-entry_of_the_month. for ex - 2018050001 for the first entry of current month. How to do this at db level

Comment: just set column as unique on db level

Comment: Its already there, but it raise an exception, to handle that exception is my exact problem

Comment: Update your code with the exception, please.